# How to make squid proxy server cache response with vary: * in header?

Tags: squid, http-caching

I'm building a system to serve the same page (even though it's not fresh anymore) when requesting the same URL within a run which can be about an hour, so I try using squid cache to cache everything. I add this to squid.conf:

> refresh_pattern ^http: 600000 100% 700000 override-expire
>   override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache
>   ignore-private ignore-no-store ignore-must-revalidate ignore-auth

However, it doesn't seem to work when the HTTP response has "Vary: *" in the header. For example, I cannot cache http://stackoverflow.com. I'm using squid version 3.1.19, if that matters.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

"Vary: *" essentially means that there are factors other than headers in the HTTP request that determine the uniqueness of a request (for example, client IP address, etc), so a intermediate cache (squid) cannot really reliably cache.

Unfortunately, Squid has *no* mechanism for ignoring the Vary header, either completely or for select headers. I'm running into this problem myself.